# Checking if its a happy number

Tags: python, numbers

So my code should take the digits of a 2 digit number for example (22) and square the individual digits so to [4, 4]. Then add these so 8. Then repeat this till the sum = 1 or repeat endlessly if it never = 1. My code so far will not work.

```
    num = int(input("--->")) #input
    sumer = 0
    numb = [int(d) for d in str(num)] #splits the input into the digits

    while sumer != 1:
        numb = [int(d) for d in str(num)] 
        numb[-1] = numb[-1] * numb[-1]
        print(numb)
        numb[-2] = numb[-2] *numb[-2]
        print(numb)
        sumer = numb[-1] + num[-2]
        print(sumb)
        numb = sumer
```

But when I do this I get the error
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     line 11, in 
     sumer = numb[-1] + num[-2]
     TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I work in python 3.4.1 Thank you

Comment: `num` is `int`; `numb` is a `str`; you mean `sumer = numb[-1] + numb[-2]` and not `sumer = numb[-1] + num[-2]`. and your `sumer` changes from `int` to `str` (and will therefore never be 1).

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sumer = numb[-1] + num[-2]
```

should be

```
sumer = numb[-1] + numb[-2]
```

You could never go out of the while loop though!